# Show output of show create table exemplo

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'am use 10.4.17-MariaDB.

In the example below.
There is a more efficient select than I am using to return the result from **Table:My result**?

*NOTE: The base has more than 100,000 lines having "N" INST_UNIV, INST_GOV and INST and The YEAR range from 2008-2012*.

*Table:data*

| ID | DOC | YEAR | Group_1 | Group_2 | Group_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INST_UNIV_A | DOC_1 | 2008 | NULL | INST_GOV_A | NULL |
| INST_UNIV_A | DOC_1 | 2008 | NULL | INST_GOV_B | NULL |
| INST_UNIV_A | DOC_1 | 2008 | NULL | INST_GOV_B | NULL |
| INST_UNIV_A | DOC_1 | 2008 | NULL | INST_GOV_C | NULL |
| INST_UNIV_A | DOC_1 | 2008 | NULL | NULL | INST_A |
| INST_UNIV_A | DOC_1 | 2008 | NULL | NULL | INST_A |
| INST_UNIV_A | DOC_1 | 2008 | NULL | NULL | INST_B |
| INST_UNIV_A | DOC_1 | 2008 | INST_UNIV_A | NULL | NULL |
| INST_UNIV_A | DOC_1 | 2008 | INST_UNIV_B | NULL | NULL |
| INST_UNIV_A | DOC_1 | 2008 | INST_UNIV_C | NULL | NULL |
| INST_UNIV_A | DOC_1 | 2008 | INST_UNIV_D | NULL | NULL |
| INST_UNIV_A | DOC_1 | 2008 | INST_UNIV_D | NULL | NULL |
| INST_UNIV_A | DOC_2 | 2008 | INST_UNIV_B | NULL | NULL |
| INST_UNIV_A | DOC_2 | 2008 | NULL | INST_GOV_A | NULL |
| INST_UNIV_A | DOC_2 | 2008 | NULL | NULL | INST_A |
| INST_UNIV_A | DOC_2 | 2008 | INST_UNIV_E | NULL | NULL |
| INST_UNIV_n | DOC_n | 2008 | INST_UNIV_n | NULL | NULL |
| INST_UNIV_n | DOC_n | 2008 | INST_UNIV_n | NULL | NULL |
| INST_UNIV_n | DOC_n | 2008 | NULL | NULL | INST_n |

**Although my result is similar to table: Expected outcome, I'm not sure it is the best procedure, as it is taking too long to present the result for n cases:**

```
SELECT 
id,DOC,`year`,
IF(ISNULL((LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Group_1))-LENGTH(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Group_1), ',', '')))+1)=0,(LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Group_1))-LENGTH(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Group_1), ',', '')))+1,0) as  Group_1,
IF(ISNULL((LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Group_2))-LENGTH(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Group_2), ',', '')))+1)=0,(LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Group_2))-LENGTH(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Group_2), ',', '')))+1,0) as  Group_2,
IF(ISNULL((LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Group_3))-LENGTH(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Group_3), ',', '')))+1)=0,(LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Group_3))-LENGTH(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Group_3), ',', '')))+1,0) as  Group_3
FROM exemplo 
GROUP BY id,`year`,DOC
```

*Table:My result*

| ID | DOC | YEAR | Group_1 | Group_2 | Group_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INST_UNIV_A | DOC_1 | 2008 | 4 | 3 | 2 |
| INST_UNIV_B | DOC_2 | 2008 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| INST_UNIV_n | DOC_n | 2008 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: I do not see the difference...

Comment: The result you show and the expected result are identical.

Comment: And why are you going to all the complexity of GROUP_CONCAT()? You should use `COUNT(DISTINCT Group_1)`  and so on. I tested, and it gives the same result.

Comment: @BillKarwin, Thank you very much. Does not make sense.

Comment: @BillKarwin their results are their expected results because they are just asking for optimization help

Comment: please edit your question to show output of `show create table exemplo;` and `explain SELECT ...rest of your select;`.

Comment: I don't understand you

Comment: @ysthI, I did the editing above suggested by you